# Typescript RxJS ajax undefined this context

Tags: ajax, typescript, rxjs

is question is very similar to many others already answered. But these solutions didnt work. Here is the problem:

Having a Typescript class which calls an RxJS.ajaxPost() On Response pipe or callback "this" is undefined.
Usually I just use arrow functions ()=>{} to get rid of it. But it dont works in this case.

Why? How to handle ajax calls correctly and using responses?

```
export class Store {
    count: number = 0;
    
    getRest(): void {
        ajaxPost('https://httpbin.org/delay/2')
                .pipe(
                        tap((response) => {
                            console.log('response: ', response, this);
                            this.count += 1;
                        }),
                        catchError(error => {
                            console.log('error: ', error);
                            return of(error);
                        })
                )
                .subscribe((resp) => {
                    console.log("subs resp", resp, this);
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: `this` being undefined in this context would have to do with how the `getRest` method is called.

Comment: Yes, that was the point. Thanks for the hint. Helped me to look further.

Answer (score 0):

Iam sorry, the error lies above!

for tests I had made 2 react components and wanted to use the getRest function directly. Of course this wont work.

In compare the upper function "addCount()" works fine.

My Fail. Sry.

```
export const Controls = observer(_Controls);
function _Controls(props: {store:Store}): any {
    return <div>
        <button onClick={() => props.store.addCount(2)}>Add 2 = {props.store.count}</button>
    </div>;
}

export const Controls2 = observer(_Controls2);
function _Controls2(props: {store:Store}): any {
    return <div>
        <button onClick={props.store.getRest} title="add">Add Rest 3 = {props.store.count}</button>
    </div>;
}
```